# How to write this into a loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, data-manipulation

I am trying to arrange my data. The csv file that I load contains results of 15 precincts for one locality. The number of rows are 150 because the names of the 10 candidates repeat for each of the 15 precincts.

My goal is to make the names of the 10 candidates as columns without repeating their names and with the results for each candidate as the values. I use the code below, however I have to do it 15 times because I cut my data in intervals of 10 to extract the results of one precinct. It's the same for "binondov". I have to cut my data in intervals of 8 because there are 8 candidates for each precinct.

Is there a way to write my code as a loop? Thanks!

```
binondop1 <- binondop[1:10,]
binondop1a <- binondop1[order(binondop1[,2]),]
binondov1 <- binondov[1:8,]
binondov1a <- binondov1[order(binondov1[,2]),]
colnames(binondop1a) = colnames(binondov1a) = 
c('X', 'Candidate', 'Party', 'Vote', 'Percentage')
binondo1 <- rbind(binondop1a, binondov1a)
binondo <- rbind(t(binondo1$Vote), t(binondo2$Vote),
            t(binondo3$Vote), t(binondo4$Vote),
            t(binondo5$Vote), t(binondo6$Vote),
            t(binondo7$Vote), t(binondo8$Vote),
            t(binondo9$Vote), t(binondo10$Vote),
            t(binondo11$Vote), t(binondo12$Vote),
            t(binondo13$Vote),t(binondo14$Vote),
            t(binondo15$Vote))
colnames(binondo) <- c('Acosta', 'Aquino', 'DLReyes', 'EEjercito',
            'Gordon', 'Madrigal', 'Perlas', 'Teodoro',
            'Villanueva', 'Villar', 'Binay', 'Chipeco',
            'Fernando', 'Legarda', 'Manzano', 'Roxas',
            'Sonza', 'Yasay')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly without seeing a sample data set, but perhaps something like this will help get you where you need to your answer.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(Candidate = c(rep('Acosta',3), rep('Aquino',3), rep('DLReyes',3)), 
                 Party = c('R','R','R','L','L','L','D','D','D'),
                 Vote = rep(c('A','B','C'),3), 
                 Percentage = c(5,4,2,6,8,3,1,3,2))

df2 <- df %>% 
       mutate(Candidate = paste0(Candidate, ' (', Party, ')')) %>%
       select(-Party) %>%
       spread(Candidate, Percentage)
```